# Breaking a URL into parts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to break a URL into parts depending on if they URL ends with a trailing slash or not.

Here are some examples:

```
1. www.example.com/
2. www.example.com/category1/
3. www.example.com/category1/subcat1/

1. category_path = /
file_name = nil

2. category_path = /category1  
file_name = nil

3. category_path = /category1/subcat1/
file_name = nil
```

Example set #2

```
1. www.example.com/page1
2. www.example.com/category1/page2
3. www.example.com/category1/subcat1/page3

1. category_path = nil
file_name = page1

3. category_path = /category1/
file_name = page2


3. category_path = /category1/subcat1/
file_name = page3
```

How should I split this URL string into a category_path and file_name path?

Note: If the URL ends with a trailing slash '/' then the URL only has a category_path and file_name will be nil.  If there is no trailing slash, the last part is a file_name.

**It seems in Rails, the request.url doesn't pickup the trailing slash.
If I output the value of request.url in my controller, it doesn't even acknowledge that there is a trailing slash**

e.g.

```
def test
   has_file = request.url.end_with?("/")
  render text: "url = #{request.url}, has_file = #{has_file}"
end
```

Now if I add or remote a trailing slash, it doesn't seem to even register.  Is a trailing slash just ignored the header level or something?

Answer (score 0):

**Routing**

I don't see any reason why you wouldn't use [nested routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) for this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :categories do
   resources :subcategories #-> domain.com/categories/1/subcategories/4
end
```

This is the *conventional* way to sort this out - allowing you to pass the variables above as [`params`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) in the controller

--

If you wanted to refactor this to get rid of the resource identifications (`categories` / `subcategories`) etc, you'll want to use the `path: ""` trick:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :categories, path: "" do
   resources :subcategories, path: "" #-> domain.com/1/4
end
```

This will translate into the following:

```
#app/controllers/subcategories_controller.rb
Class SubcategoriesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      params[:category_id] #-> 1
      params[:id] #-> 4
   end
end
```

Comment: I want to support a dynamic # of nested categories and subcategories, and also don't want ids.